# IDE for Windows Mobile 5.0 Professional

Tags: ide, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-5.0

I've been asked to write a piece of code for a Windows Mobile 5.0 Professional device.

My day to day code of choice is Java, but I'm up for a challenge, so I'm going to give it a go.

So what IDE and SDK should I be using?

I've downloaded Visual Studio 2010 (via msdn), but I'm not sure its the right choice.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks
Jeff Porter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Visual Studio 2008 Professional (2010 has no device support other than Phone 7) and the Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK(s) - either [Pocket PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=83a52af2-f524-4ec5-9155-717cbe5d25ed&DisplayLang=en) or [SmartPhone](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=dc6c00cb-738a-4b97-8910-5cd29ab5f8d9&DisplayLang=en), whichever you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks! I'd reached the same conclusion late last night after 8GB of downloads (2008 Express, 2008 Pro and 2010).